# .NET Core packages

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am struggling to find reliable source of documentation of all Microsoft packages available for .Net Core solutions, both Asp.Net and Windows Forms. I was unable to find even list of all packages with short description of their purpose and functionality.

Yes, all packages can be found in NuGet but the documentation is usually missing, the real documentation as we used to have delivered with .Net Framework and its libraries.

Furthermore some packages, predominantly the really basic / core ones, been have replaced by others between .Net Core 1.0 and latest .Net Core 3.0, what makes this even more difficult and less transparent.

Comment: At the time of writing, there are 173,558 packages *just on nuget* (which isn't everything). A list of each one and what they do - *even in brief* - would be a very long list to author or consume. Are you talking about the MS bits? if so: learn.microsoft.com; if not, you're going to have to be more specific...

Comment: Yes, I meant MS packages. Have edited question.

Comment: That still leaves probably 10,000+ packages. Microsoft has many profiles on Nuget, the [Microsoft](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Microsoft) one has almost 5k packages on its own.

Comment: Number of classes available for .Net Framework was huge as well, but well documented.

Comment: So; what actually *is* the question? again: learn.microsoft.com is a good place to start if you're talking about the MS bits, and when you're targeting .NET Core 3, you actually get *a lot more* included by default *anyway* (i.e. when targeting .NET Core 3 you usually need very few, if any, additional package references to system/BCL bits). All I can see here is an observation: "there's a lot of things in .NET" - yes, yes there are.

Comment: I would like to understand how packages evolved between .NET Core 1 and 3, see what are the options. Some packages are still versioned as 2.2 - shall I use them, or have been they replaced by others? Number of questions, were I believe proper documentation would help. I will deep dive into learn.microsoft.com

Comment: @Megrez7 it isn't possible to give a specific single answer to that; it will *depend on the package*, but **in general**, yes, you can still use things; just because they haven't been updated for 3.0 doesn't mean they are obsolete - `System.Buffers` hasn't had an update since May 2018, for example, and that is *absolutely key* to huge parts of .NET / Core. You'd have to ask about a single specific package to get a meaningful answer to that.

Comment: Another problem I met. Look at Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Headers. Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.net.http.headers?view=aspnetcore-3.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.headers?view=aspnetcore-3.0 is missing general description of these APIs. So how can I know what is the purpose of the API, when to use which one without deep diving onto docs and studying all the documentation? Again with .Net Framework that was much more clearer.

Comment: That's a reasonable problem to be concerned about, but it's not an answerable question for Stack Overflow. It's not at all clear to me what an answer would look like here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, understand there is no such documentation at the moment and that is the answer. How could we raise this issue for future to be solved?

Comment: You could file a *specific* issue at https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues. But again, really not a Stack Overflow thing..

Comment: On NuGet, each package has its dependencies listed, including framework dependencies. If .NET Core/.NET Standard isn't listed, it's not compatible. Most of the confusion between similar packages such as `Http.Headers`, is because one is for .NET Framework/ASP.NET, and the other is for .NET Core/ASP.NET Core. As far as versions go, all the Microsoft package major versions follow the .NET Core major versions. So 2.2 packages, for example. are for .NET Core 2. 3.X packages would be for .NET Core 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually looked first time at core level, what I am able to find is this:

Source Code:
**.NET Core:** https://github.com/dotnet/core#net-core-home

**ASP.NET Core:** https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore

That indeed you are aware, what can help more are few tools to get more information :

**.NET Core Source Browser** https://source.dot.net/
Here you can actually look for actual code for methods e.g. I searched for StringBuilder & result is showing in picture
[image]

**Reference Source for .NET (not core)** https://referencesource.microsoft.com/
Similar for Source Browser for .Net but more exhaustive with documentation & examples.
[image]

**.NET API Browser** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/
It is collective source in which you can look for every public API made by Microsoft starting from .Net Core, .Net, UWP, Office, Xamarin, Visual studio, Powershell, etc to name a few along with different version of API. 
[image]

Hope it helps to search what you are looking.
For specific topics in depth you will need to search on internet for latest articles & blog which can help a lot along with very helpful Micrsoft community on SO & MSDN.